# ¿Tiene dos significados la palabra "repugnante"?

Tags: definiciones, significado

Normalmente se emplea para describir algo **repulsivo** o que provoca rechazo, pero lo oí utilizar también para describir a una persona caprichosa, propensa a rechazar o expresar desagrado, es decir, una persona que **repugna** en el sentido activo del verbo.

¿Es correcto emplear así la palabra?

Comment: Yo creo que en sintaxis la palabra repugnante... se refiere a algo que causa repulsión ó asco.
Pero para referirse a el comportamiento de alguien, creo es mejor usar Repunoso... (Que sería como una persona desagradable... que nadie es de su agrado) 

Answer (score 5):

La respuesta corta... Si.

Según la RAE [repugnante](http://dle.rae.es/?id=W5zGHWH) es:

> 1. adj. Que repugna.
> 2. adj. Que causa repugnancia (‖ aversión).

La definición 2 se refiere al uso más común de tu primer ejemplo para describir algo repulsivo.

La acepción 1 se refiere a tu segundo ejemplo cuando alguien es caprichoso y repugna, rehusa o rechaza algo.

La primera y quinta acepciones de **[Repugna](http://dle.rae.es/?id=W62Tidm)** en la RAE son:

> 1. tr. Rehusar, hacer de mala gana algo o admitirlo con dificultad.
> 2. intr. Causar aversión o asco

Comment: Muchas gracias. Lo imaginaba pero me alegro de tener una segunda opinión.

Answer (score 1):

El segundo uso que descibes a mi me se me parece más a `repelente` que a `repugnante`. Desde luego, algo puede ser repelente porque da asco (es repugnante), pero algo pude repelernos sin llegar a dar asco.

Por ejemplo, si una persona es muy machista o racista (siendo esos rasgos que ti te molestan en extremo), su actitud te puede causar "asco" (un desagrado muy fuerte) y puedes tildar a esa persona (o su actitud) de repugnante. Sin embargo, quizá esa persona símplemente está siempre quejándose (o es aburrida o cuenta chistes muy muy malos...). Tanto, que no te apetece estar con ella, porque te deprime y te hastía. Esa persona te repele, te causa aversión, pero no necesariamente asco.

Así que para mi gusto (y a nivel práctico), hay una fina linea que distingue el uso de "repugnante" dependiendo de si causa rechazo por ser asqueroso o de muy mal gusto o no. Yo no calificaría a alguien de repugnate simplemente por ser repelente / repulsivo aunque técnicamente el significado de esos términos permita hacerlo. Para mi una persona caprichosa no es necesariamente repugnante, aunque sí replente a cierto grado.

En conclusión, no creo que se pueda tachar a una persona de "repugnante" simplemente porque su actitud repele o aleja a los demás. El motivo de tal repulsión o el nivel de desgrado es para mi lo que hace que se pueda usar el término o no y por eso cuestiono un poco su uso en ese sentido.

Comment: Gracias. Entiendo que es poco frecuente el uso de este modo.

Comment: Estoy parcialmente de acuerdo con lo enunciado pero creo que hay algo mal interpretado aquí. Según la RAE en la definición 1 una persona es repugnante cuando esa persona repugna o rechaza otras cosas. La definición 2 si se refiere a cuando la persona causa aversion o rechazo en otras (p.ej: es un indigente que no ha tomado un baño en meses).  En ninguna de las dos definiciones se mencionan motivos físicos, morales, etc.  Para mi técnicamente y **prácticamente** si se pueden usar ambas definiciones para referirse a una persona independientemente del motivo por el cual rechaza o causa rechazo.

Comment: @DGaleano, como digo, esto es a nivel "práctico". No creo que la mayoría de la gente use o entienda "repugnante" con la definición #1. Si a alguien le presento varias ideas y me las rechazas todas y a consecuencia digo que "es repugnante", la gente va a pensar que estoy cobrado por su actitud y le estoy insultando, en lugar de pensar que le estoy definiendo de acuerdo a la primera acepción. Para mi ese significado es un _tecnicismo_ que está cayendo en desuso.De hecho, creo que la gente lo entendería mejor si digo que es un **repugnador** (como sinónimo de "rechazador")